# Bulk vectors in elasticsearch using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and I think I'm missing some hints.
I'm trying to put some data into an index using python, that's my code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
import json
df = pd.read_excel('analisi rna.xlsx')
```

data are something like this:

```
name      content       doc_vector
  0    some_text    list of embeddings of the text in col 2
```

17 rows only

```
client = Elasticsearch("https://something",
                     api_key="xxx" )

client.ping()
True 


mapping = {
   "mappings": {
       "properties": {
           "name": {
               "type": "text" 
           },
           "content": {
               "type": "text"
           },
           "doc_vector": {
               "type": "dense_vector",
               "dims": 768
           }
       }
   }
}



response = client.indices.create(
   index="prova_vettori",
   body=mapping,
   ignore=400 # ignore 400 already exists code
)

response
ObjectApiResponse({'acknowledged': True, 'shards_acknowledged': True, 'index': 'prova_vettori'})


json_str = df.to_json(orient='records')
json_records = json.loads(json_str)


action_list = []
for row in json_records:
   record ={
       '_index': "prova_vettori",
       '_source': row
   }
   action_list.append(record)


helpers.bulk(client, action_list)

BulkIndexError: 17 document(s) failed to index.
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I've tried to follow many other similare questions (part of the code is infact copied and pasted from other answers), as well as youtube tutorial, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps, try it with _client.index()_ first, one by one? It would give you the clue what's wrong with your _row_

Comment: Another suggestion. Instead of ignoring the 400 error you should delete the index, this way you will avoid the situation when existing indexing with the same name would prevent you from changing the mapping. If all these recommendation don't work, please post how your row looks like. And what errors you are getting.